# How set restriction for input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to validate input length.

1. Set min length and max length.
2. Show validation message when user enters less / more character.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.showText = this.showText.bind(this);
        this.showText2 = this.showText2.bind(this);
      };
      showText2(e) {
        this.setState({ text2: e.target.value });
      }
......
      <input defaultValue={this.showText} onInput={this.showText2} /
```

Comment: can you explain little more ?

Comment: i have got input. When users write less 6 symbols program write 'youк sumbols less 6'

Comment: Details in question was missing. What exactly needed was not explained in detail

Answer (score 0):

You can define validation like this - [validation demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/validation-38u4f)

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: "",
    errors: {
      username: ""
    }
  };
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { errors, username } = this.state;
    if (username.length < 6)
      errors.username = "You name must be more than 8 charater";
    else errors.username = "";

    this.setState({ errors });
  };
  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          className="username"
          name="username"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your username"
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.username}</span>
        <input
          type="submit"
          className="btn buttonFont buttonStyle"
          id="logInButton"
          value="LOG IN"
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @user12522448 check this created for you

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function or some class for validation which take time and not cover all thing, or better, you can use validators library for validating client-side live validation, which provide many Validators, for example, validate phone, character length, email, date, URL, or even regex ... etc.

some popular validation libraries:

- [validate.js](https://validatejs.org/)
- [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to things in order to validate an `input`, a function that validates the input value and a UI to show when the input has wrong values, like this:

```
state = {
  inputError: false,
  inputValue: ''
};

handleChange = e => {
  if (e && e.target && e.target.value) {
    // Here you could check whatever condition for the value of the input
    // For example that the value has more than 6 characters
    if (e.target.value.length > 6) {
      this.setState({ inputError: false, inputValue: e.target.value });
    } else {
      this.setState({ inputError: true, inputValue: e.target.value });
    }
  }
};

render() {
const { inputError, inputValue } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      {inputError && 
        <span>You need to write at least 6 characters</span>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

In order to do it better, you could at some CSS to reflect the error in the Input (red border or some kind of alert that the input value is not correct). Hope this helps.